# logback error JMS

Tags: java, groovy, jms, activemq-classic, tibco-ems

Can you please share if you have a another appender for tibco ems (tibjms).
I'm new to Tibco EMS your any help is really appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain exactly what's happening, not just "not working".

Comment: Can we use the same JMSQueueAppender for tibjms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `TibjmsConnectionFactory` where the appender needs a `QueueConnectionFactory`, but it doesn't implement that interface. Use `TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory` instead.

Comment: No, *use* `TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory`.